# Reduce the photo size before upload

Tags: ios, image-resizing

For my iPhone Web App, since the 3G network is very slow, it cannot upload a large photo. Thus, I want to reduce the photo size before I upload it into a server. I tried to use `CANVAS HTML 5`, which works in Android but not in iOS 7 or 8.

Are there any other methods that I can use to reduce the photo size before upload?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to compress the photo.

***compressionQuality***

***The quality of the resulting JPEG image, expressed as a value from 0.0 to 1.0. The value 0.0 represents the maximum compression (or lowest quality) while the value 1.0 represents the least compression (or best quality).***

See more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/

Comment: this is Web App, not the native APP